# TFS 2015: Creating a Work Item Alert throws tf50309 error

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, alerts

[TFS-WorkItemAlert-Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqkKE.png)

Trying to create a team-level work item alert throws the 'tf50309' error. My account is in the 'Project Admin' group and have all admin privileges.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be a **team administrator**:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am one of the Administrators for the project but the issue persists.

Comment: Did you add your account as Administrator in your team "Portal"  (not project) as the screenshot shows?

Comment: Yes, I am in the group of Administrators for the team 'Portal'. Pardon me, can't add screenshots to the comments

Comment: Did you try to add another account and test with that account? Check the groups your account belongs to see whether there is a deny permission in any group. Also, try to clean the server cache C:\TfsData\ApplicationTier\_fileCache.

Comment: Hello, I checked to see there were no permission denials but still couldn't add alerts. However, I tried to create a separate team and was able to add the same team level alert without any issue. This is really confusing why I am restricted for Portal team. Thank you again.

Comment: How about "Not set" permission? Did you try to change them to allow?

Comment: I had to explicitly add the allow permission to all common groups the user was associated with. None of which had deny, but there was a combination of "Not Set" and "Inherited".